# Enable Python extension for GeoServer 2.16.x

Tags: python, geoserver

I am using Windows 10 (64 bit) & QGIS 3.4 along with GeoServer 2.16.x in my machine

I am trying to enable 'scripting' in GeoServer (so that will develop Python scripts) but it gives me error (my GeoServer is crashing)

Tried following :

Followed https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/scripting/installation.html & nightly build https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/

- All my GeoServer folder has proper rights and permissions
- Tried to downgrade to version 2.14, still getting same error(GeoServer is crashing)
- Whenever I remove files from the  'lib' folder then GeoServer works properly

Update :-

- Default Python is installed on my machine (version : 3.8)
- In Logs not getting any specific error

[image]

- Thinking to make custom build (it's required lots of time)

Checking alternatives on my side...

Comment: Did you check the catalina log file in Tomcat installation folder?

Comment: What is the "default python" on windows 10? What error message do  you get when it crashes